# Basic understanding of Amazon AWS and Product Advertising API

Tags: .net, web-services, amazon-advertising-api

I'm completely new to Amazon AWS development and the Product Advertising API. I have some basic questions I'd like to get answered...

I'm building a website for a client who would like to sell his own products. Placing the products on Amazon.com and using AWS from his website seems like an okay bet, right? I'm not experienced in "point of sale" websites as far as handling credit card info, etc., but it seems like Amazon has that part covered. As long as our items are listed on Amazon, we just need to make the appropriate AWS calls to create and interact with their shopping cart remotely. Is that an accurate assumption?

I've created an account with AWS. This gave me the access identifiers (security keys) to make the web service calls. I've also signed up for the "amazon associates" to get an associate tag. I can successfully make the web service calls which is all well and good...

However, I'm a little confused. The "amazon associate" stuff seems like it is mostly referral based.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/HowDoIMakeMoneyUsingA2S.html

states:

"You earn referral fees when you join the Amazon Associates program and the users you refer to Amazon sites buy qualifying products."

We're going to be selling our own products. So, I don't think any referral is applicable in our case. How does this work when you sell your own products?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not all that familiar with Amazon's retail services, but I think you're looking for the [Amazon Webstore](http://webstore.amazon.com/).

I don't think AWS is how vendors sell their own products on Amazon. AWS is a set of general-purpose tools and APIs for building websites, web services, and the like. It has, as far as I know, nothing to do with putting your own products on Amazon.com.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! I will certainly look into Amazon Webstore. Thank you for sharing and passing that along. But you still should be able to use the Product Advertising API to hit your own Amazon Webstore, correct? I don't see any reason why you wouldn't be able to... I can read into it, but I thought you might know off hand. Thanks again!

Comment: _"But you still should be able to use the Product Advertising API to hit your own Amazon Webstore, correct?"_ That sounds right to me. But, you still need to create your Webstore, and you don't do that using AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a year old, but it may help others to know there is a new API for Sellers:
https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html?group=products&section=products&version=latest